# How to create an array of all random orderings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an array which stores all possible orderings over n numbers. Is there any efficient way to create such an array in Python 3?

For example, when n is 20, there should be 20! elements in this array.

Comment: `20!` is equal to `2432902008176640000`, which is a _really_ big number.  Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: look into itertools module.

Comment: I would rather go with a generator

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, 20 may be too large for this case. I just want to know a way to create such an array while smaller n is also fine. I want to output all orderings with a specified math property which I am studying. So I think I should check it over all possible orderings.

Comment: All random possible orderings? Could you clarify please?

Comment: Take a look at [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: @Axium For example, when n is 5, the ordering [1,2,3,4,5] has the specified property I need while the ordering [2,1,3,4,5] does not. I need to output all the orderings like [1,2,3,4,5] with such property. At this moment, the only way to find out if an ordering has the property is to do some computations and comparing the results. So I have to obtain all possible orderings first and check them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficient methods, maybe, practical, no.

Producing an in memory list is not efficient, as you say, your list will be `20!` elements long, each element being a list of 20 items. Assuming best case that each element is 1 byte, and there is no overhead, our array will consume `20 x 20!` bytes of RAM, around 42 [exabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte)

@user8408080 suggests using a generator, a function that produces each element, but one at a time, so it can be processed without having to store the entire list in ram, @njzk2 suggests itertools, the `permutations` method might do what you want:

```
itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
```

or more simply:

```
itertools.permutations(range(1,21))
```

Next problem, this produces 20! results, it might be feasible to process `10,000,000` a second (though you haven't specified what will be done with this list), given that it will take `20! / 10^7` seconds, around 7,000 years.

Assuming there was a more "efficient" method, we could get that number down, but i'd argue its still not practical.

```
import itertools

def process(l):
    #Do some processing
    return l

def iterate_permutations(n):
    for l in itertools.permutations(range(1,n+1)):
        process(l)

iterate_permutations(10)
```

You may have to look at re-defining your problem, or optimising it so you don't have to handle all possible permutations in turn. Depending on the problem there may be some mathematical or logical principal to help you.